# Fail to write image in Oracle from ZipInputStream byte array

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa

I follow several example from SO to get image file from zip, and put each file bytes into a hashmap:

```
final byte[] zip_file = ((CommonsMultipartFile) zip_file).getBytes();
zip_stream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zip_file));

try {
    while ((entry = zip_stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(baos, BUFFER_SIZE);
                try {
                    int count = 0;
                    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                    while ((count = zip_stream.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
                        dest.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    dest.flush();

                    filelist.put(entry.getName(), baos.toByteArray());
                    baos.reset();
                } finally {
                    dest.close();
                }
            } finally {
                baos.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        zip_stream.close();
    }
```

Later when reading from `filelist`, the byte array will persist into a java bean, just like this

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
byte[] image = fileist.get(imageFileName);
customer.setImage(image);
```

`Customer` is an JPA entity that field `image` is with `@Lob` type. So this part shouldn't have any issue.

The sad party is after the whole transaction there did some data write into 'image' field but from Oracle (using SQL developer) the bytes cannot compose to image file, which means from oracle the file is broken. There must be something wrong make the bytes corrupted. How can I make it work?

### UPDATE

change inputstream-outputstream transfer using `IOUtils.copy` but still not working...But I feel something wrong here but don't know how to fix. **in following code the looping seems to work on each entry of the zipInputStream, entry is never visited instead of the file name, is it look normal**?

```
 try {
        while ((entry = zip_stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(zip_stream, baos);
            } finally {
                baos.close();
            }
            filelist.put(entry.getName(), baos.toByteArray());
        }
    } finally {
        zip_stream.close();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can use something more reliable as IOUtils.write instead of managing your own streams. Also, maybe @Lob is fine on Hibernate side, but is the referenced image Column of the proper Oracle type? Or do you use autogenerated schema?

Comment: @baba. Thank you for the reply. I think everything good on oracle side as we use another UI to save/load image directly, it works OK. So the problem is from Java side. Do we have any example for IOUtils.write on image object? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove baos.set and move the filelist.put after baos.close.

Honestly I think one should nest dest and baos inversely, and dest.close should suffice, imply closing baos.

Also instead of getBytes one could do getInputStream.

Certainly there is [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) with a `copy`; somewhere there should be a copy with a flag "keep opened."

---

Directory entries were not skipped and closeEntry not called.

```
    try {
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("D:/dev/... .zip"));
        ZipEntry zipEntry;
        while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("- " + zipEntry.getName()
                + " #" + zipEntry.getSize());
            if (zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                zipInputStream.closeEntry();
                continue;
            }

            long size = zipEntry.getSize();
            if (size > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                throw new IOException("File too large: " + zipEntry.getName());
            }
            int reserved = size == -1L ? 8192 : (int)size; 
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(reserved);
            IOUtils.copy(zipInputStream, baos);
            zipInputStream.closeEntry();

            baos.close();
            File file = new File("D:/dev/data/temp/" + zipEntry.getName());
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, baos.toByteArray());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Stackoverflow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Are we saying remove baos.reset() and move filelist.put after baos.close? I tries but still get same problem. Could you please be more specific about `nest dest and baos inversely`? Also use getInputStream instead of getBytes on which object?

Comment: Added code, in stand-alone style. **closeEntry** and directory entries might caused the problem. I felt a buffered stream more a responsibility of IOUtils.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's very helpful, yes I think the zipInputStream.closeEntry(); play an role to make it finally work :)